# Uncaught Error: Script error for: isotope/js/layout-mode

Tags: requirejs, jquery-isotope, packery

I need to use (this is the standalone package)isotope.pkgd.js  with packery-mode as LayoutMode for my project. Im using require.js for wiring my js stuff in an AMD.
Below is my html code:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="section">
                    <header class="section-header">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <h3><span class="fa fa-image"></span>Photos</h3>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="padded_content">
                        <div id="region-gallery" class="gallery js-isotope">
                            @foreach (IPhotosComponentMediaImage image in Model.Images)
                            {
                                ++count;
                                if (w60h40Nums.Contains(count))
                                {
                                    addClasses = " w60 h40 ";
                                }
                                else if (w40Nums.Contains(count))
                                {
                                    addClasses = " w40 ";
                                }
                                else if (w60nums.Contains(count))
                                {
                                    addClasses = " w60 ";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    addClasses = "";
                                }
                                <div class="gallery-item isotope-item @addClasses">
                                    <div class="inner lazy" data-original="@image.MediaImageUrl" alt="@image.MediaTourName" data-description="@image.MediaImageDescription"></div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My RenderLayout.js

```
define([
    'domReady!',
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'event.aggregator',
    'app',
    'util/searchOptionsUtil',
    'util/UriUtil',
        'gallery-carousel',
        'isotope',
        'packery-mode'
], function (doc, $, _, Backbone, Marionette, EventAggregator, App, SearchOptionsUtil, UriUtil, gc,Isotope, pm) {
    var regionPhotosLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        el: $('#region-photos'),
        initialize: function () {
          var $container = $('.container');
           console.log($container);
            $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector: ".gallery-item",
                    layoutMode: "packery"
                });

            var gallery = $("#region-gallery");
            //Modal carousel
            //var gallery = $("#region-gallery");

            gallery.galleryCarousel({
                imgSelector: ".inner",
                imgSrcAttr: "data-original"
            }); 
        }
    });

    return regionPhotosLayout;
});
```

So when I run my code. I get following errors where its not able to find this file layout-mode.js. I dont know why I would get the masonry error. Im trying to use the packery mode here. Moreover do we have to specifically add this layout-mode.js that isotope is looking for. I tried finding but didn't find any file by that name that I could download.

```
GET http://local.gocollette.com/js/libs/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min/js/layout-mode.js 
Uncaught Error: Script error for: isotope/js/layout-mode
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'masonry' of undefined
```

Thank you in advance. Hope to find a solution for this.
Thanks,
Kasturi

Answer (score 1):

The packery layout mode is not included in isotope.pkgd.js and must be installed separately. This is the layout-mode.js I think.

The download is [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html)

Comment: I have downloaded the packery layout..separately. And included that in requireJs and used in the renderedLayout page.  Am I including it in a wrong way?

Comment: Do i need to initialize that packery-mode included in renderedlayout.js . If yes how do i do that?

Comment: Did you see this [reference](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#requirejs)? Especially the part " layout mode that’s not included", of course your layout would be packery.

Comment: As you can see Im doing the same thing as suggested in the link.

Comment: I'm not so up on require.js but I'm not seeing "To use Isotope as a jQuery plugin with RequireJS and isotope.pkgd.js, you need to run jQuery bridget". Also, layout-mode should be changed to the name of your packery script. (Script error for: isotope/js/layout-mode)

Comment: Please give some inputs. Im still stuck at it.

Comment: I would need a jsfiddle or a link.

Comment: Sorry, your jsfiddle is not helpful since you just pasted the code in the html.